# Why do I use web services in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I have made several web applications in web2py. I have also written web services in web2py for mobile clients. In web2py, controller can return dictionary for views. So web2py dictionary can use in view and for web services also. My question is so why should I use controller which is specific for web services?

```
@request.restful()
def api():
    def GET(*args,**vars):
        return dict()
    def POST(*args,**vars):
        return dict()
    def PUT(*args,**vars):
        return dict()
    def DELETE(*args,**vars):
        return dict()
    return locals()
```

Instead this I can use simple controller which returns dictionary and I can call that function with json extension.

```
def index():
    return dict()
```

Comment: It's not a controller for web services, it's for now a simple HTTP [REST](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) interface which implements the necessary HTTP methods.

Comment: I agree that it's a simple interface which implements GET, POST, PUT and DELETE method. What's the benefit of that interface? I can create same response from simple controller method also.

Comment: Look into the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services). _The @request.restful() decorator makes sure that the extension in the path info is stored into request.extension, maps the request method into the corresponding function within the action (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE), and passes request.args and request.vars to the selected function._ You can also implement all this by yourself. But the decorator will map to the right method and pass the arguments automatically.